# elasticsearch post query with a large body, amout 3m, How should I optimize it?

Tags: elasticsearch

my example as following:

```json
GET plan_tab_spl_th_es_canal/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "debt_no": ["1800053310649400333", "..."]
    }
  }
}
```

the body debt_no field length is about 100000, it is too large.

if exist something i can do, for example es support deliver multi request and return the result last?

Comment: I am really confused about what you are trying to achieve here. Performing lookup on 100000 terms is a very heavy operation, that's why there is a limit there. If you can explain the reason for this, maybe we can come up with a more optimal solution. Let's start with where do you get these 100000 debt_no terms?

Comment: @imotov hi bro, thanks for you reply. 
In fact, the length of terms will reach 500,000, which is too big for one http request and exceeds the limit of client_max_body_size. Can it be divided into two requests? The first time only sends half the parameters to the ES server, and ES does not return Data, after sending another 250,000 data for the second time, es will return the data?

Comment: This is not a way to work with ES. We should take a few step back and understand why you end up needing to filter +100k terms. Could you walk us through your the bigger picture ?

Comment: @zuoyuan yes you can hack you way around it with a temporary index, but the problem is not in the request body size. The request body size is just a safety mechanism that is there to prevent other issues. The moment you find your way around this safety mechanism you will run into other issues. I would love to help you avoid these issues but since you don't want to answer my questions and clarify the problem, I cannot give a responsible answer. As Paulo said, this is not how ES was designed to work. We need to solve the issue that brought you here.